# マルチモニタの画面切り替え

Tags: java, c#, c++, windows

モニターを4枚接続できるグラフィックボードをWindows10のPCに接続して、
画面の出力状態を切り替えるアプリを作りたいと思っています。
4枚のモニターを1つのモニターとして扱って動画などを再生したり、
4枚のモニターをそれぞれ独立した画像、動画などを再生したいと思っています。

Windowsが標準でもっているDisplaySwitchをコールすれば良いかと思っていましたが、
1つのモニターとして表示する事ができないようでした。

何か**C#、C++、Javaなどで組み込める方法**で、
マルチディスプレイの**画面出力方法を切り替える**方法をご存知の方がいましたら
ご教示お願いできないでしょうか。

Answer (score 2):

考え方としては、「モニタや画面出力方法を切り替える」のではなくて、「ウインドウを表示する位置・サイズを各モニタの担当する領域に移動する」ということです。

以下にC++での情報の取得方法が示されています。
[【高DPI】デスクトップの物理座標系を得るには？【WinAPI】](https://qiita.com/marksard/items/ef3c1846de1d7cae2989)

> デスクトップ矩形には仮想デスクトップ矩形と普通のデスクトップ矩形があります。
>
> モニター毎のデスクトップ矩形
>   　モニターごとのデスクトップ矩形。
>   　さらにモニター矩形とワーク矩形（タスクバー領域を除いた矩形）があります。
>
> 仮想デスクトップ矩形
>   　使用中のモニターすべてを内包する、仮想的に一枚のデスクトップに見立てた時の矩形です。

上記情報を元にSetWindowPosでウインドウの位置・サイズを指定・変更すれば良いでしょう。
[SetWindowPos関数](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/cc411206.aspx)

おそらく動くサンプルが以下になるでしょう。
[マルチディスプレイ時の各ディスプレイの座標を取得する](http://yamatyuu.net/computer/program/sdk/base/enumdisplay/index.html)

あと上記例にもありますが、DPIや個々のサイズの違うマルチモニタの場合の考慮も必要です。
[(Windows10)高DPIと通常DPIのマルチディスプレイ環境は結構大変](https://3ryupg.hatenablog.com/entry/2018/02/23/000036)
[秀丸エディタ 新機能の紹介(Per-Monitor DPI対応)](https://hide.maruo.co.jp/software/hidemarunew/v869_1.html)

Comment: kunif様  
  
uchinoです。  
情報をいただきましてありがとうございます。  
モニターを拡張状態で接続して、  
Window画面をそれぞれのモニター座標に表示するということですね。  
  
今回NVIDIA QUADRO P620のグラフィックボードを購入していまして、  
付属していたツールで切り替えができていたので  
これと同じことをやりたいと考えていました。  
実は、昨日メーカにも問合せをしていて、開発ツールの紹介をいただきました。  
（メーカー提供のモジュールを使って実現するような内容でした。）  
1画面と4画面の切り替えそのものはwindowsの標準では実現が難しく、  
kunif様の情報のように画面を拡張して座標で表示するのが一般的な方法なんでしょうか。

Comment: 申し訳ありません。  
不慣れで改行を入れようと思いましたが、  
うまく入れられませんでした。  
(半角スペースを入れてみましたが、改行が入らないですね。)

Comment: コメントでは改行は使えません。画面構成を、その時々でプログラムから柔軟に変更したい場合は、拡張状態の方が良いでしょう。1画面/4画面のモード切り替えそのものは[DisplaySwitch](http://apis.jpn.ph/fswiki/wiki.cgi?page=WinCmd%2FDisplaySwitch)コマンドで出来るのでは？

Comment: 重ね重ねコメントありがとうございます。確かに教えていただいた方法ならグラボによらないので良さそうですね。1画面/4画面の話は私の書き方が悪くて申し訳ありません。それぞれモニターは4台で、大きく出すか分割して出すかの表現で使いました。　　コメントで改行は使えないのですね。教えていただきありがとうございます。